# Failed to initialize the excel reader - spring batch job

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I wrote a job to read an excel file based on the github project spring-extension-excel,

the code is as below:

```
<bean id="VignetteItemReader" class="excel.poi.PoiItemReader">
<property name="resource" value="Vignettes.xlsx" />
<property name="rowMapper">
    <bean class="excel.mapping.PassThroughRowMapper" />
</property>
</bean>
```

but I face this error:

> org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader

it gives me that it's caused by:

> java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type

PS: the xls files are red correctly, the problem is when I work with the extension : .xlsx

any suggestions?

Comment: Provide link to that github project and most likely reader is not able to find file specified with `resource`. Try something like `value=classpath:Vignettes.xlsx"` if that file in on your `classpath`.

Comment: without stacktrace is hard, but probably resource property value is wrong; add full file path or classpath:\

Comment: I dnt think so.. the error is not caused by the classpath :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it was a configuration that has to do with the pom.xml : 
I should have added the following tags :

```
    <resources>
              <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <excludes>
                         <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
                          <exclude>**/*.xlsx</exclude>
                          <exclude>**/*.xls</exclude>
                          <exclude>**/*.csv</exclude>
                    </excludes>
              </resource>
              <resource>
                  <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                  <includes>
                    <include>**/*.version</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
              </includes>
              </resource>

              <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                    <includes>
                         <include>**/*.xml</include>
                          <include>**/*.xlsx</include>
                          <include>**/*.xls</include>
                          <include>**/*.csv</include>
                    </includes>
              </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
              <testResource>
                    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
              </testResource>
        </testResources>
```